Backdrop from under the faucet in bathroom is no longer sitting right with faucet
The backdrop for my sink faucet is no longer sitting flush with it. It hangs down now so water gets in now behind the faucet underneath where that backdrop is supposed to keep it out of. It’s causing it to leak under the sink what can I do about that outside of putting on a whole new faucet.

This question isn't answerable (inasmuch as it is a question). Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Put some thought into what you've shared and what's reasonable to expect in return. (I haven't the slightest idea what a sink faucet backdrop might be.)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
